# Creating a table from .csv file using PDI Kettle

Tags: mysql, csv, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm new to PDI and I'm working with PDI Kettle, I have 40 .csv files with different number of columns ,I want to create tables out of those files in a single transformation, I have used a "CSV File Input" step to select a file and "Table Output" step to create table but for creating 40 tables out of those 40 files I  again need to select these two steps,so is there any way to create all 40 tables in one go in a single transformation is it possible,pls help me with the same
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can load all 40 files into one table, but i am not sure whether you can load all 40 files into 40 different tables..

Comment: There is sample in KETTLE_HOME/samples called dynamic table creation

Comment: After loading all 40 files into one table, I think here is no means to separate all those into different tables based on columns.

Comment: Please give more information about your input and your expected output for us to be able to help.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. A couple questions tho: how do you relate table names to file names? Is the table name exactly the file name without the .csv extension? And is this mapping fixed (meaning the same file name will always map to the same table name)? Alternatively, you could put everything into one table and add a column to contain the filename it came from. Then you could create 40 different views if you need to.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers the table name is same as the file name without .csv extension & mapping is also same, the column name & column number is different in each .csv files ,also there is another way to create table manually in mysql and then load your data into the table via pentaho but this method is not efficient to create table so I'm looking for an alternative wherein I won't be able to create table first in mysql and then load the data into it from pentaho. kindly help......... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in Pentaho with the standard steps is a bit involved. To read the CSV and get the headings, and then read the data, you need to use `ETL Metadata injection`.

First read the header with columns name, and use `ETL Metadata injection` to read the data in another transformation.

To auto create the databases is not straight forward, as this is something the main developer of Pentaho discourages.

Here is the answer and an example of how to auto create a table: [Perform an auto CREATE TABLE to store the output of a transformation](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?95166-Perform-an-auto-CREATE-TABLE-to-store-the-output-of-a-transformation).

So you would run a job, that passes the filename and tablename to a transformation. The transformation will use `ETL Metadata injection` to read the CSV into correct fields and `meta.getSQLStatementsString();` to get the DDL of the database to store the data.

Comment: This is great.... ETL Metadata injection is helpful in my scenario....Thanks @bolav